# Add a click listener to a div not (yet) created

Tags: jquery, append, onclicklistener

When I click a div, I append (under some conditions) another div to the document via jQuery. I would like to create a click listener to this new div. Here is the code and **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtK4H/)**:

```
<div class="test">click me!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.test').click(function() 
{
    $(document.body).append('<div class="close">close</div>');
});

$('.close').click(function() 
{
    $('.test').hide();
    alert('close clicked');
});

</script>
```

My goal is to register a click listener to `close` div, to handle future clicks, but it seems it doesn't work if the div is not created yet. How can I do? I would like to avoid to register a click listener after each `close` creation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at delegated events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it will make event work on dynamically added html:

```
$(document).on('click','.close',function() 
{
    $('.test').hide();
    alert('close clicked');
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff55w/)